# how to install an USB Printer on windows Embedded without Plug&Play

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to install a USB printer on a Windows standard embedded system without Plug & Play functionality and without the Hardware Wizard.

To install a printer using `.inf` file I use the following code:

```
sprintf(c_Buffer, "rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ii /f %s", FileName);
system(c_Buffer);
```

After this function I can use the Windows wizard to add the printer.

Is there a way to use also this or a similar function to install a USB Printer?